# oPaging is undefined with datatables and twitter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

On a project, I use datatables 1.10.2 with, to have pagination with bootstrap style, this script :

```
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
    bootstrap: {
      fnInit: function(oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
        var els, fnClickHandler, oLang;
        oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
        fnClickHandler = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
            return fnDraw(oSettings);
          }
        };
        $(nPaging).addClass("pagination").append("<ul>" + "<li class=\"prev disabled\"><a href=\"#\">&larr; " + oLang.sPrevious + "</a></li>" + "<li class=\"next disabled\"><a href=\"#\">" + oLang.sNext + " &rarr; </a></li>" + "</ul>");
        els = $("a", nPaging);
        $(els[0]).bind("click.DT", {
          action: "previous"
        }, fnClickHandler);
        return $(els[1]).bind("click.DT", {
          action: "next"
        }, fnClickHandler);
      },
      fnUpdate: function(oSettings, fnDraw) {
        var an, i, iEnd, iHalf, iListLength, iStart, ien, j, oPaging, sClass, _results;
        oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
        iListLength = 5;
        an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
        i = void 0;
        ien = void 0;
        j = void 0;
        sClass = void 0;
        iStart = void 0;
        iEnd = void 0;
        iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);
        if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
          iStart = 1;
          iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
        } else if (oPaging.iPage <= iHalf) {
          iStart = 1;
          iEnd = iListLength;
        } else if (oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
          iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
          iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
        } else {
          iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
          iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
        }
        i = 0;
        ien = an.length;
        _results = [];
        while (i < ien) {
          $("li:gt(0)", an[i]).filter(":not(:last)").remove();
          j = iStart;
          while (j <= iEnd) {
            sClass = (j === oPaging.iPage + 1 ? "class=\"active\"" : "");
            $("<li " + sClass + "><a href=\"#\">" + j + "</a></li>").insertBefore($("li:last", an[i])[0]).bind("click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($("a", this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
              return fnDraw(oSettings);
            });
            j++;
          }
          if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
            $("li:first", an[i]).addClass("disabled");
          } else {
            $("li:first", an[i]).removeClass("disabled");
          }
          if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
            $("li:last", an[i]).addClass("disabled");
          } else {
            $("li:last", an[i]).removeClass("disabled");
          }
          _results.push(i++);
        }
        return _results;
      }
    }
  });

  if ($.fn.DataTable.TableTools) {
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
      container: "DTTT btn-group",
      buttons: {
        normal: "btn",
        disabled: "disabled"
      },
      collection: {
        container: "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
        buttons: {
          normal: "",
          disabled: "disabled"
        }
      },
      print: {
        info: "DTTT_print_info modal"
      },
      select: {
        row: "active"
      }
    });
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
      collection: {
        container: "ul",
        button: "li",
        liner: "a"
      }
    });
  }

}).call(this);
```

It works when I have a single datatable but when I have multiple datatables it break at the line `if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {`. I seen than `oSettings.oInstance` is null for all datatables expect the last one.

What can I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

add the plugin below

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
            {
                return {
                    "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
                    "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
                    "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
                    "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
                    "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
                    "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
                    "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
                };
            };
```